# How to reinitialize the variable within the constructor in java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, constructor

I have a servlet class like this:

```
        public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {
        Object obj;

        public ServletClass (){
        //obj is initialized by reading the "filename" from the method readFile
         obj=readFile(filename); 
        }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

           // the value of the obj is modified inside this method.
        }

 }
```

Now on some user click event,I want to re-initialize the Object "obj" by reading from the file inside the constructor.

How can I do this? If this is not the right way to do it, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For one, constructors are invoked only once for a given instance. Two, `Servlet` instances are used across multiple threads. Your implementation is not thread safe.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  Is there a way at all if user wants to discard the changes to "obj" and restore it to initial value read from the file?

Comment: `Object obj= null;

    @Override
    public void init() {
       obj=readFile(filename);
    }`

Comment: The constructor is only executed once. Why therefore are you constraining the solution to lie 'within the constructor'? And why is the object a class member in the first place? You need to continue/commence your reading about servlets, sessions, scopes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

constructor in java is used to initialize the instance of an Object and it is called only once upon initialization (`ServletClass obj = new ServletClass ()` in your case this is usually done by the servlet container). So you cannot call constructor again from inside any method of that class.

What you need to do is call the appropriate method :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       obj=readFile(filename); 
}
```

Thats acceptable!